# Display different images in same frame when hovering over different text messages

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok I'm stumped. Im trying to figure out how to hover over different words to show an image in the same location. So if I click pizza I'll see a pizza but if I click burger I'll see a burger in the same frame the pizza was displayed. Heres what I got so far. No JQuery. Solely JS and html. Thanks in advance.

JS

```
function displayImage(item) {        
  switch (item) {   
    case "pizza":
      document.getElementById(showImage).src = "pizza.jpg";     
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<h2>Main Course</h2>
  <ul>
    <li onmouseover="displayImage('pizza')">Pizza</li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="description">
  <iframe width="100%" height="415px" name="showImage" /></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get an element by `id` but you haven't add an `id` to your element. You should use `document.getElementsByName("showImage");`

If it doesn't work it is because your image must not be in the same folder as your js file. The below example works. I just replaced with an online image.

```js
function displayImage(item) {        
  switch (item) {   
    case "pizza":
      document.getElementById("showImage").src = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496518908709-02b67989c265?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80";     
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Main Course</h2>
<ul>
  <li onmouseover="displayImage('pizza')">Pizza</li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
 <div id="description">
  <iframe width="100%" height="415px" id="showImage" /></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my end. I've tried both Id and Name - neither worked. I'm thinking I'm doing something else wrong.

Comment: Not that `getElementsByName` will return an Array, not the Element itself. So you may need to iterate or do a `document.getElementsByName("showImage")[0]`

Comment: @TaharKhan, don't forget the quote sign as well. Your code `document.getElementById(showImage)` would search for a **variable** `showImage` and not the **string** "showImage"

Comment: I've added the quotes and did document.getElementsByName("showImage")[0]. Still couldn't get it to work. I've also tried switching out getElementByName to getElementById but still can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @TaharKhan try to update the question with your modified code. If you run the code provided in Mart's answer, it's working.

Comment: That did work for me. I'm curious why my code with the edits provided still doesn't work. See below.

My code
function displayImage(item) {
 switch (item) {
         case "pizza":
  document.getElementsById("showImage").src = "Chips.jpg";
 }
}


Marts Code
function displayImage(item) {        
  switch (item) {   
    case "pizza":
      document.getElementById("showImage").src = "Chips.jpg";
  }
}